# Get current branch and store as variable using bash

Tags: bash, git

When I'm working with Kubernetes, I want to run commands that depend on my active branch. For that reason, having aliases would help me with other aliases that automatically run commands, given the current branch.

I'm trying to store the name of the current active local branch into a bash alias using a function, so that I can run other scripts without worrying about specifying the active branch, but I keep encountering an error on this.

```
function branch ()
{
    local result='git branch | grep ^\* | cut -c 3-';
    echo "$result"
}

alias get_branch=$(branch)
```

But when I try to run this, I get:

```
    usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
               [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
               [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
               [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
               <command> [<args>

.... (Same output as just entering 'git')
```

(`cut -c 3-` removes the `*` and space following it when active git branch gets listed)
e.g.

`* feature/ch20372
ch20372
ch12345`

The strange part is both of these work:

```
alias IMLAZY='git branch |grep \* | cut -d " " -f2'
alias TEST='git branch | grep ^\* | cut -c 3-'
```

Which makes me think

1. Could be syntax issues with my `~/.bash_aliases` elsewhere?
2. Issue with ZSH somehow?
3. Syntax error somewhere in the function
   definition?

Comment: I was trying to follow: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon No... this is only tangentially relevant to that question. Sure, I'm using a similar command, but I want to know how to save this in a bash alias from a function.

Comment: The error doesn't seem related to the code you're showing.

Comment: What should happen if you enter `get_branch`?

Comment: I just tried running your code and it worked properly. How are you running this snippet of code? The error you are getting and the code do not seem to be related.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+%5Bgit%5D+current+branch+variable

Comment: @Cyrus the result should print the current working branch without * or space.

Comment: @Benjamin W. It seems that error was syntax related, but it seems like there's still an error; I've updated the question.

Comment: The question, at least, is using single quotes rather than backquotes (or preferably `$(...)`). As written, you aren't going to get the usage message you claim, because nothing will run `git`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alias IMLAZY='git branch |grep \* | cut -d " " -f2'
```

:)

Comment: I think I might have had syntax errors in my bash session that carried over, when I tried to re-write things. It seems I was defining the function incorrectly somehow, but still not sure what I did wrong. I'm still confused why this and `alias git_branch='git branch | grep ^\* | cut -c 3-'` weren't working before.

Comment: Not sure. `alias git_branch='git branch | grep ^\* | cut -c 3-'` worked for me

Comment: `git branch | grep '*'` is an anti-pattern.  Get the branch name with `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Answer (score 5):

Could be simpler to use the appropriate plumbing command : [git rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)

*(Named here `gitcb` for current branch, can be arbitrary)*

```
alias gitcb='git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but OP specifically asked for bash in title.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Yes, I've wondered if it was the reason of the downvote. But it was unsure that OP actually needed a bash alias. I figured it could have been a bad assumption on his part and waited for clarification. But you might very well be right nonetheless. Anyway, both our solutions work, I guess he'll be fine either way :-)

Comment: Yeah, needs to be a bash alias, clarified reasoning/purpose in the question

Comment: @Dave Liu thanks for clarification. Editing.

Comment: @DaveLiu Why are you writing a function at all to generate the body of the alias, and why do you "need" an alias in the first place?

Comment: @chepner because I don't know how else I would do this. Usually, I use functions to generate the body of the alias in order to automate certain parameters that I don't have to specify. When I'm working with Kubernetes, I want to run commands that depend on my active branch. For that reason, having aliases would help me with other aliases that automatically run commands, given the current branch.

Comment: I challenge you to find a situation where `git cb` (as defined in the previous version of this answer) would fail where a `bash` alias (that has to call `git` anyway) would succeed.

Comment: @chepner string length

Comment: You might want to elaborate on that.

Comment: I admit I share chepner's doubts. Are we missing something in the picture?

Comment: @chepner The point is, I want a variable that I can insert somewhere else. Sure, technically if I assign this to an alias, it works. But I would need to do an additional step to evaluate the definition. I already knew 3+ ways to get the current branch name, before making this question. I'm trying to figure out:
 1) Why MY code isn't working.
 2) How to incorporate this into other functions/aliases
 3) How to store the result of a function in a variable

Yes, `alias=` is a pedantic, small additional step, but I took off my downvote as soon as @RomainValeri amended his answer.

Comment: I thought I might need to do something like `alias asdf=$(git cb)`, but that didn't work for me. That additional step might seem trivial, but it wasn't.